# Kubernetes service usage for NLB from different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, dns, terraform, nlb

I have a requirement to add  kubernetes Service with an ExternalName  pointing to NLB(in a different AWS account).
I am using terraform to implement this.
I am not sure how to use NLB info external name section.
Can someone please help?

```
   resource "kubernetes_service" "test_svc" {
      metadata {
        name      = "test"
        namespace = var.environment
        labels = {
          app = "test"
        }
      }
      spec {
        type          = "ExternalName"
        **external_name =** 
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of external name is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: prod
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.database.example.com
```

Try to put the NLB CNAME as the external name

Comment: Please ignore..I was using uppercase characters for LB name.It is resolved now.

Comment: @Kumar Glad to hear that :)